# Access Value of an array in php inside of another Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get values from array inside of another array. I have seen lots of answers here about this but i cannot manage to do so. I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [listingid] => 1234
            [availability] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [von] => 2015-11-07
                            [bis] => 2016-03-19
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [von] => 2016-03-19
                            [bis] => 2016-03-28
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [von] => 2016-03-28
                            [bis] => 2016-07-30
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [listingid] => 5678
            [availability] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [von] => 2015-11-07
                            [bis] => 2016-03-19
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [von] => 2016-03-19
                            [bis] => 2016-03-28
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [von] => 2016-03-28
                            [bis] => 2016-07-30
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

and i do this to get values:

```
foreach($first as $key => $value){
    echo "Value: " . $value[$key]['availability']['von'] . "<br>";
}
```

which normally should work based on the answers i saw but it gives me empty value.

I have also tried this:

```
foreach($first as $key => $value){
    $listid = $value['listingid'];
    echo $listid;
}
```

and this gives me the value of the listingid. How can i get values for von and bis?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look how you access `listingid`: `$value['listingid'];` and how you access `availability`: `$value[$key]['availability']['von']`. And also look in which dimension both of those keys are..

Comment: Compare `$value['listingid']` and `$value[$key]['availability']['von']`, so you know the first one works. Now also compare where those two keys are located: `listingid` and `availability`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to run a nested loop.

```
foreach($first as $value){
   echo "Listing ID:".$value['listingid'];
   echo "<br/>";
   foreach($value['availability'] as $availability) {
         echo "Value: " . $availability['von'] . "<br>";
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot...i was trying this: 

`foreach($first as $key => $value){
 //$listid = $value['listingid'];
 foreach($first['availability'] as $availability){
  echo "Value: " . $availability['von'] . "<br>";
 }
 
}` but it was giving me errors.....

Comment: That's because you used $first['availability']. Should have used $value['availability'] instead. :)